# VFP group header from map

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, wrapper-class, repeat

Here is the inner/wrapper class and the VFP. I am currently getting this display where the Product_Group__c repeats for every code. I want to display the group once and repeat all codes and  values under it. I included VFP snippet and example of what I want.

[image: VFP]

[image: Desired]

```
   public class ProductsController {
    public class ProductGroup { // wrapper class
       public Products_Groups__c pg {get; private set;}
       public List<Products__c> products {get; private set;}       
    }

    // VF page map
    public Map<String, productGroup> productGroupsByproductCode {
        get { ... population not relevant                           
              return productGroupsByproductCode;
        } private set;
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="ProductsController" standardStylesheets="false">
        <div>Products</div>
        <table>
            <apex:repeat value="{!productGroupsByProductCode}" var="productCode">
                <apex:repeat value="{!productGroupsByProductCode[productCode].options}" var="prod">
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!productGroupsByProductCode[productCode].pg.Product_Group__c}"/></td></tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!prod.PDC_Desc__c}"/></td>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{!prod.Value_Desc__c}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
</apex:page>
```

### Sample Map data

```
   {ACA=ProductGroup:[
     Products=(Products__c:{PDC__c=ACA, PDC_Desc__c=Tire Size, Value_Desc__c=255/70R 22.5, Id=a1I2f000001KUYwEAO}), 
     pg=Products_Groups__c:{
      Product_Group__c=Tires / Wheels / Hubs and Drums,
      Product_Code__c=ACA, Id=a1C2f000001jCyYEAU}],
```

Comment: please use [edit] and show `productGroupsByProductCode`; also - I thought you were using a custom `Products__c` rather than OOTB `Product2`

Comment: I edited and added the map. I am using Products__c, that was an error from copying from the other post. Also, is there an easy way to keep the order that comes from products_groups__c? There are sequenced numbers there for sorting the data. I included them in my map code above,

Comment: hmm -- looking at what is being rendered now, I fear the map is not built correctly and this could be because I misunderstood your data model due to the confusing use of plurals in object names. Can you go back to the earlier post and show the schema in a diagram with sample data by field name

Comment: I appreciate your continued help @cropredy. I went back to the original and added data structure, sample data, and desired output.